# SQL Server : SELECT DISTINCT Group By with Count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, count, distinct

I have a table as below.

[image: sample]

Is it possible that I can make the output as above?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want the latest date for each id. But what msg do you want for each id? I'm assuming that in reality each msg won't simply be "msg..."?

Comment: msg... means just message like hi blabla...

Comment: do you have primary key in the table?

Comment: we don't want, what the message could be.    We want to know if you want to show latest message, as you want the latest date to be displayed. Or do you mean message will be same in all records from smith/linda

Comment: Yes. there is a primary key as msg_id(integer)

Comment: Ok, so when there are multiple records for a given id, which record's msg do you want to show? It's not clear from your example since all your msg values are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Comment: SELECT tbl_msg.msg_id, tbl_msg.msg_sender, tbl_msg.msg_receiver, tbl_msg.msg_content, tbl_msg.msg_date, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname FROM tbl_msg LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_msg.msg_sender = tbl_users.user_no WHERE (tbl_msg.msg_receiver = 'staff') GROUP BY tbl_msg.msg_sender ORDER BY tbl_msg.msg_date DESC

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MYSQL Query to do that

SELECT id, date, msg, COUNT(id) AS count FROM table_name GROUP BY id

Comment: My real query is SELECT tbl_msg.msg_id, tbl_msg.msg_sender, tbl_msg.msg_receiver, tbl_msg.msg_content, tbl_msg.msg_date, tbl_users.user_fname, tbl_users.user_lname FROM tbl_msg LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_msg.msg_sender = tbl_users.user_no WHERE (tbl_msg.msg_receiver = 'staff') GROUP BY tbl_msg.msg_sender ORDER BY tbl_msg.msg_date DESC

Comment: But error  Column tbl_msg.msg_id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.msg, t2.msg_count 
FROM table_name t1 
JOIN (SELECT max(msg_id) as mid, count(*) as msg_count FROM table_name GROUP BY id) as t2 
ON(t1.msg_id=t2.mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want latest date in the result set, so the query would look like something,
SELECT id, max(date), msg, COUNT(id) AS count FROM table_name GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

For sql server, try this :

```
SELECT id, max(date) as date, msg, count(id) AS count 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id, msg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.id, Q.max_date, count(T.msg)
FROM Table1 T, (select id, MAX(dateD) as max_date from Table1 group by id) Q
where Q.id=T.id
group by T.id, Q.max_date
;
```

Comment: Please consider adding some description to your answer, just pasting a code snippet might solve the immediate problem at hand but not add any understanding or long term value.