# Select rows where string does not repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to phrase this, but I have two tables that I use `INNER JOIN` on to count the number of records I have. This works fine but the problem is that I have some rows in `table1` where some of the records have a string that can appear in another record. Something like this:

```
table1                   table2
------                   ------
id    string             id    table1_id    some_column
01    aaa                01    01           1
02    bbb                02    02           3
03    aaa                03    03           1
04    ccc                04    04           4
05    bbb                05    05           2
...                      ...
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

This query works fine, but I want to be able to get distinct values. So my query should bring me back only these records:

```
table1                   table2
------                   ------
id    string             id    table1_id    some_column
01    aaa                01    01           1
02    bbb                02    02           3
04    ccc                04    04           4
...                      ...
```

As you can see, it doesn't show any additional records where they share the same string. What would I write after or before my `INNER JOIN`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the table 1

```
select count(*) 
from (
    select min(id) as id, string 
    from table1 
    group by string
) t1
inner join table2 on t1.id = table2.table1_id
```

Answer (score 1):

using [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to select the top 1 per group of `string`.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by string order by id)
  from t1
)

select count(*)
  from cte
    inner join t2
      on cte.id = t2.table_1id
     and cte.rn = 1
```

using a subquery instead of the cte:

```
select count(*)
  from (
    select *
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by string order by id)
    from t1
  ) sub
    inner join t2
      on sub.id = t2.table_1id
     and sub.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about common table expressions and how to use it! Looks very handy.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT count(*) from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id

This will give you the count of distinct values in the tables

Comment: Thank you, however, this still returns all the records.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want the count you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.string)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

Some of the other answers are clearly better if you want do do something with the distinct values other than just count them.