# Get unique count of instance SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is something I am not getting for some or other reason.

I have a list of records

```
BusinessUnitId     Position      Date          Time
-----------------------------------------------------------
76                 Staff         3/30/2009     11:00:00 AM
76                 Staff         3/30/2009     04:00:00 PM
76                 Management    3/30/2009     05:00:00 PM
78                 Exco          3/30/2009     09:00:00 AM
78                 Staff         3/30/2009     09:30:00 AM
```

If I do a group by

```
select 
    count(answer.BusinessUnitId)
from 
    AnswerSelected answer
group by 
    answer.BusinessUnitId
```

I retrieve a value of `3` and `2`

What I am trying to achieve is get a count of `2`

So in total `2` business units submitted answers, `76` and `78`(hope this makes sense)

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct

Comment: select count(distint BusinessUnitId) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT BusinessUnitId)
FROM AnswerSelected
```

You don't need to use `GROUP BY` in this particular case to get the distinct count of business units across your entire table.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester