# getting distinct count on join of two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables where primary key of first table is used as foreign key for second table. In first table primary key is having unique values but in second table as foreign key it is having duplicate values as well. Now i want count from both the tables at same time and using left join for that.
I have tried the following query :-

```
 select distinct count(c.joined) as joined,
    count(t.JobReqID),t.Country from txrecruitment as t 
    left join CandidateDetails as c on t.JobReqID=c.Jobreqid 
    where t.status='open'
    group by t.Country
```

The count value of count(t.JobReqID) is not giving count of distinct JobReqId which i want. The result of count is counting the multiple instances of 2nd table also which i want to remove.
What should be the right way to do this. Any help is welcomed!!

Comment: Please share your expected result and actual result as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count using `DISTINCT` for the **JobReqID** like below :

```
select count(c.joined) as joined, count(distinct t.JobReqID), t.Country 
from txrecruitment as t 
left join CandidateDetails as c on t.JobReqID=c.Jobreqid 
where t.status='open'
group by t.Country
```

Comment: thanks both of you @kabir. It solved my problem but what can be the possible reason that count(c.joined) is giving count as one less than actual count. thanks again!!

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark it as useful (upvote) :)

Answer (score 1):

Because our distinct is not placed in the correct location. Use Distinct Inside the Count.

```
 select count(distinct  c.joined) as joined,
    count(DISTINCT t.JobReqID),t.Country from txrecruitment as t 
    left join CandidateDetails as c on t.JobReqID=c.Jobreqid 
    where t.status='open'
    group by t.Country
```

Comment: using count(distinct c.joined) is not helping, it is giving all the count as 1 @jayasurya

Comment: Might be because for each Country joined ID has only 1 unique value. In that cause , you may just remove the distinct from that