# MySQL Distinct guidance needed

Tags: mysql, distinct

My Goal: Display the names of the top 10 users who have submitted the maximum number of revision in one changeid. (A change can have multiple revisions)

```
Select DISTINCT(rev_authorUsername), COUNT(rev_id) as revnum FROM t_revision
group by rev_authorUsername, rev_changeId
 order by revnum desc
 limit 10;
```

I get the top 10 authors but I get duplicate names. Any help pls??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `DISTINCT` modifiers applys for the selected set, do not use parenthesis  around `rev_authorUsername`
2. Using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP_BY` (here with different columns) [may have some unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164544/6709630):

> (…) cavalier treatment of "Group By" and "Distinct" could lead to some
>   pernicious gotcha's down the line if you're not careful.

What about this request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rev_authorUsername, COUNT(rev_id) as revnum
FROM t_revision
ORDER BY revnum DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

*(The use of `DISTINCT` & `GROUP BY` is explained in the [MySQL Reference Manual - SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).)*

Comment: I think the OP is interested in counting distinct `rev_id`s with `COUNT(DISTINCT rev_id)`, rather than what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets surrounding `rev_authorUsername` after `DISTINCT`, they shouldn't be there and might be what's messing with your results.

Comment: Answers should be explanatory and in most cases should contain code examples. If you don't want to go into that much detail consider writing a comment instead

Comment: While true, this won't make any difference- the distinct keyword shouldn't be there either