# Using row_number (or alternative) to count by group, and also only distinct per group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count distinct values per account id using `row_number()`

This is an example of data that I have:

```
ID | val
_____________
1  | a
1  | a
1  | b
2  | a
3  | c
3  | a
3  | b
4  | d
4  | d
5  | a
```

I want to basically count unique values per unique ID. I have tried to use `row_number() partition over`.

This is an example of the output I want:

```
ID | val | rank | count
_____________
1  | a  | 1  | 2
1  | b  | 2  | 3
2  | a  | 1  | 1
3  | c  | 1  | 1
3  | a  | 2  | 1
3  | b  | 3  | 3
4  | d  | 1  | 2
4  | e  | 2  | 2
5  | a  | 1  | 1
```

I've tried this:

```
%sql
-- Show 
select * from (
select `ID`,`val`, dense_rank() over (partition by `ID` order by `val` asc) as row_num
from table1
)
order by `ID` asc
```

Which resets the counts based off of new ID, but doesn't count distinct val's. AKA gives me this:

```
ID | val | rank
_____________
1  | a  | 1
1  | a  | 2
1  | b  | 3
2  | a  | 1
3  | c  | 1
3  | a  | 2
3  | b  | 3
3  | b  | 4
3  | b  | 5
4  | d  | 1
4  | d  | 2
4  | e  | 3
4  | e  | 4
5  | a  | 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Comment: Check out `DENSE_RANK()` and try `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID, val)` [This link](https://codingsight.com/methods-to-rank-rows-in-sql-server-rownumber-rank-denserank-and-ntile/) may help.

Comment: Where did "e" come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` to order them . . .

```
select id, val, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
from t;
```

However, the resulting rank is going to be alphabetical.  Your sample suggests that you want to keep the original ordering.  If so, first you need a column that expresses the ordering.  Then, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select id, val, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by min_oc)
from (select t.*, min(<ordering column>) over (partition by id, val) as min_oc
      from t
     ) t
```