# mysql count from table where related record exist in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have 2 tables, customers and addresses.  I want to count how many customers have addresses with `name` like a given search term

something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countSearch FROM customers,addresses WHERE address.cu_id=customer.id AND customer.name like ?
```

Table Customers

```
 ________________
| id   |  name   |
 _________________
|  4   |  john   |
|  5   |  mark   |
 _________________
```

Table address

---

```
| id   |  cu_id   | address  |
 ____________________________
|  1   |  4       | ADRESS!! |
 _________________
```

Comment: Use explicit rather than comma joins. AND What;s the question do you not understand how like works or something else?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a inner join to connect both tables

This wouldm show how many addresses c.name has

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countSearch 
FROM customers c INNER JOIN addresses a
     ON a.cu_id  = c.id
WHERE c.name like 'test'
```