# How to get the number of time a particular number appeared

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want count the number of times a single data occured in a column, how can I achieve that using mysqli. For instance I want to know the number of times Victor appeared in the column of name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL server:
SELECT name, count(1)
from Tablename
where name like 'Victor'
group by name

This query will give you results like - eg Victor appeared 22 times:
Victor 22

Is this what you're looking for?
Please provide more information so its easier to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try window functions

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name DESC) 
  AS Total, Name from table
```

Answer (score 0):

this one will give you count of records with name='Victor'

```
select count(name) as cnt from t where name='Victor'
```

this one will give you all names with counts

```
select name, count(1) as cnt
  from t
 group by name
 order by name
```