# Count occurrences of value in a grouped SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I want to count the number of times a column value appears in my returned grouped data.

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM whatever
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

I'm looking for a count of the distinct values with the returned data.  So not rows in the database, but the new grouped table.

SELECTs within SELECTs hurt my head so please be gentle.

Comment: Use that query result as source for another aggregate query. Add tag for database platform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/selecting-count-with-distinct)

Comment: It helps with SQL questions that you include an example of the expected that matches your example input dataset. You will get more insightful responses if you create a _fiddle_ (search for Db Fiddle or SQL Fiddle) and post the link to it in the question. You should also tag the post with the specific database vendor (as is explained in the SQL tag wiki)